# How to read file that has been downloaded on selenium grid for protractor e2e tests?

Tags: protractor

Here is my capabilities settings :

```
capabilities: {   

    browserName: 'chrome',  

    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
        prefs: {
            'download': {
                prompt_for_download: false,
                directory_upgrade: true,
                default_directory: process.cwd()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it fails when I am trying to read this file 
also I tried adding '/temp to the default directory please advise

Comment: What is the problem? Is the file . not being dowloaded at desired location? or file is downloaded at desire location but unable to read its content?

Comment: Do you have the documentation for prefs download?